# Tools to create and update snowfalke tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any tool to compare a table with a base table and generate an alter script? once the alter script is generated, using the same alter script it should update the base table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean, but Snowflake offers a variety of connectors. If nothing else, you can write a standalone application (like with Java or Python) with any scripts you'd like to accomplish getting and running DDL statements.

Answer (score 1):

I wish there was. A lot of us are looking for that magic tool right now. As of right now, there are no tools that do true Schema compare. At least not very well. There are some tools that attempt to do this but make some assumptions under the hood that are sometimes not good assumptions. DBeaver does a little bit of this Data Grip is another tool. There are a couple more out there but again, many of these tools are assuming Snowflake is like all the other databases, which leads to bad scripts.

Comment: I don't understand why/how the workflow where you are needing to recover the "design" on the DB from the DB itself, given all changes to the DB are done by something, what was the something that made changes that you are trying to post event capture. And why are changes not planned and deployed in a controlled manor..

Comment: There are numerous reasons for this. One of the biggest reasons, which is what I believe Rajesh is eluding to is when you are building a declarative CI/CD pipeline or process. You would take either an existing script or object in Snowflake and compare the script that you are wanting to implement to generate an ALTER SCRIPT of the diffs between what exists and what you want to deploy. The ALTER SCRIPT is what is then executed. This is an extremely popular approach in other database systems like SQL Server, Oracle, IBM, etc.